# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:WithRowAnimation without freeze UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I try to understand what is the best practice to use when I work with `UITableView` with large number of row to insert when the table is visible.

**This is my behavior:**

I have one `UITableView` and one Thread that try to insert a data into this table. I think that make a `[UITableView reloadData]` is a poor solution for the performance aspect, and I know that `UIKit` operation are be carried on main thread, for this reason when the datasource update is completed I tried to send a `NSNotification` to make a `UITableView` update operation (beginUpdate - insertRowAtIndex - endUpdate) on the main thread, but this technique freeze the user interface. I have to work with 1000+ number of rows.

Someone has already solved this problem ? Is it a possible solution the use of GDC async and sync? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you try like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableDatalist insertObject:obj atIndex:index];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    });
```

Comment: Worked for me.. thanks so much for your prompt reply. i hope that anybody with 15 reputation mark this like accepted answer.

Comment: You can't accept answer without 15 reputation? I'm also not very clear  about the rule as well. :)

Comment: Someone accepted my answer with less than 10 reputation. The accept icon is on the left side of my answer. If you can't check, may be bug, but it doesn't matter, I'm pleasure to help you!