# iOS Simulator and Device Freeze after insertRowsAtIndexPaths and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Whenever I click on my table view row to insert a large row below it (370px) it freezes, but only if the row I am clicking on is near the bottom of the screen.  The CPU usage goes up to 100% and memory continues to increase but no error.

I have already viewed this question and this didn't help [UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:WithRowAnimation without freeze UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482323/uitableview-insertrowsatindexpathswithrowanimation-without-freeze-ui)

here is my code -- self.sectBool basically tracks whether or not we have inserted the row

else if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 4){
            self.sectBool = !self.sectBool;

```
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:4]];


        if (!self.sectBool) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self.tableview reloadData];
                [self.tableview beginUpdates];

                [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:4]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
                [self.tableview endUpdates];
                //[self.tableview reloadData];
            });


        }
        else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self.tableview reloadData];
                [self.tableview beginUpdates];

                [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:4]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
                [self.tableview endUpdates];
                //[self.tableview reloadData];
            });

        }



    }
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you solved this problem?